# (PostgreSQL pgcrypto) How to generate blowfish hash without salt?

Tags: postgresql, pgcrypto, cryptography

In PostgreSQL, using the `pgcrypto` module, I can generate a **slow** hash with blowfish (or any supported algorithm) like this:

```
crypt('SomeTextHere', gen_salt('bf'));
```

However, it auto-generates a salt (with `gen_salt`) and requires it. I don't want to use any salt. I am also not interested in using a normal hashing function (like sha256). How can I generate a **slow** hash without a salt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trivial to use the same salt every time.  Just do it:

```
 select crypt('SomeTextHere','$2a$16$aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
```

If you don't want any salt at all, you would need to go write some code to implement that.  That is certainly not a DBA task.